# how to set gas limit & fix UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT error

Tags: gas

The function below works fine until the point where `await thePool.exchange(fromCoin, amountToSell, toCoin);` is called - I get:

`error: UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT`,

`reason: 'cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit',`

I want to set the gas limit, but don't know how to. I've looked on the ethers docs and found that

```
transactionRequest.gasLimit ⇒ BigNumber | Promise< BigNumber >

The maximum amount of gas this transaction is permitted to use.`
```

No idea how to implement it though. I've tried `await thePool.exchange(fromCoin, amountToSell, toCoin, {gasLimit: 2000000});` but still the same result

```
// Executes the trade
async function executeTrade(fromCoin, toCoin, amountOfFromCoin) {
  // Loads the pool address we're using
  const thePool = await factory.loadPool(globalPoolAddress);

  // Sets amount to sell & converts to string
  const amountToSell = amountOfFromCoin.toString();
  try {
    console.log("Commencing pool.exchange with $"+(amountToSell/(10 ** 18))+" of "+fromCoin+" pool to " +toCoin);
    await thePool.exchange(fromCoin, amountToSell, toCoin);

    return {
      "status": "success",
      "data": "Exchanged $"+(amountToSell/(10 ** 18))+" of "+fromCoin+" pool to "+toCoin,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return {
      "status": "fail",
      "msg": err,
    };
  }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7W5a9.png
```

Comment: What contracts are you using?

Comment: dhedge sdk factory